# apt update Failed to fetch, ERROR on building Docker image

Tags: docker, debian, apt

Description:

- When run docker image building command

`docker build -f server3d.dockerfile . -t rcss3d/rcssserver3d:latest --no-cache`

- Part of Error message as below

```
E: Failed to fetch http://172.18.7.250/files/31720000019B085F/ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fonts-dejavu/fonts-dejavu-core_2.37-1_all.deb  File has unexpected size (1068028 != 1040712). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 172.18.7.250 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:f2b3f7f51e23e0493e8e642c82003fe75cf42bc95fda545cc96b725a69adb515
    - SHA1:15970026c98abf7a150d20697aa16d10d72740ba [weak]
    - MD5Sum:be036b423d84ce26700dacdbdcddf7b5 [weak]
    - Filesize:1040712 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

- My platform is `Ubuntu 16.04.6` with Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a (The problem maybe platform-independent?)
- It occured a few times on my PC, and almost each time on Docker.
- http://172.18.7.250 is probably a server in my local area network, I have no idea why it just redirect to it, maybe some cache mechanism?
- I tryed to `apt update` first and replace my `source.list` with better one, just error as the same.
- I tryed to build docker image with `--no-cache` option, it also doesn't work.
- When I switch to another network(not in local area network above), the problem should disappear, in that case, the problem may be solved.
- I wonder why this error occurs and other approaches to avoid(like block ip 172.18.7.250)

Well, it is just a wierd and no big problem...
But it always appears and makes me confused.

Answer (score 0):

I use `docker-compose` but I think it can be helpful:

1. add `apt-get update` to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

...

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
```

2. rebuild your container using no cache:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache %container_name%
```